# EF4 - Invalid Column Name after Azure Cloud Service Deployment

Tags: sql-server, azure, entity-framework-4, azure-cloud-services

Good day,

I have added a varchar column to a table in my DB.

I updated the model through VS 2015 and everything is running smoothly on my local machine.

After deploying the changes to Azure, the app is now failing with the SQL Exception "Invalid Column Name: ".

Both my local application and the azure instance run off of the same database instance.

It's failing when a db.Entity.Single() call is being made.

The entity model has the new column in the select, but for whatever reason it coming back as invalid.

I'm relatively new to debugging Azure instances, and the SQL profiler is showing that the DB connection is correct.

Any help is appreciated.

Let me know if I am not providing enough detail.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how this happened but one of the VMs under my cloud service in Azure had an incorrect connection string. The SQL profiler was actually picking up one bad connection and one good one.

I redeployed my application with the Visual Studio build agent again and the problem was solved.

My guess is that a human error was made on this particular VM but I can not be sure.

When in doubt with database connections, always double check all connection strings.